# RequireJS, MVC, and Kendo with Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, requirejs, single-page-application

I am trying to build a test site working off of this article using RequireJS, MVC, and Kendo:
[ASP.NET MVC 5 : A .NET Developer Primer for Single-Page Applications](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn605877.aspx)

It seemed pretty straight forward so following along I built my app.js,main.js, and router.js . (see below) Once I had everything straight, or at least I thought I did, I fired site and it seems to have navigated to the Index.cshtml file correctly but will not load the contents. I is generating the following error:

**Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <**

At the first "<" in the Index.cshtml file. This struck me as an issue with:

**layout.showIn("#content", kendoView);**

method so I fired off a ticket to support. They fired back with it seems to be a RequiredJS configuration issue and that is a 3rd party product which we don't support.

This is my first foray into using RequireJS, so here I am, any help you can give me to get this test running would be appreciated.

Thanks,

router.js

```
define(['kendo'],
    function (kendo) {
        var router = new kendo.Router({
            routeMissing: function (e) {
                console.log(e.url);
                console.log(e);
            }
        }),
            layout = new kendo.Layout("<div id='header'>some header</div><div id='content'></div><div id='footer'>some footer</div>");

        layout.render($("#app"));
        var indexmodel = { foo: "This is index view model" };

        router.route("/", function () {
            require(['/webapitest2/home/index'], function (view) {
                loadView(indexmodel, view);
            });
        });



        router.route("/webapitest2/home/index", function () {
            require(['text!/home/index'], function (view) {
                loadView(indexmodel, view);
            });
        });


        var loadView = function (viewModel, view, delegate) {
            var kendoView = new kendo.View(view, { model: viewModel });
            kendo.fx($("#content")).slideInRight().reverse().then(function () {
                console.log(kendoView);
                layout.showIn("#content", kendoView);

                if (delegate != undefined)
                    delegate();

                kendo.fx($("#content")).slideInRight().play();
            });
        };

        return router;
    });
```

main.js

```
/// <reference path="main.js" />
require.config({
    paths: {
        // Packages
        'text': 'webapitest2/scripts/text',
        'router': 'router',
        "jquery": "../kendo/jquery.min",
        "kendo": "../kendo/kendo.all.min",
        "jszip":"../kendo/jszip.min",
        "aspnetmvc": "../kendo/kendo.aspnetmvc.min"

    },
    shim: {
        'kendo': ['jquery']
    },
    priority: ['text', 'router', 'app']
});
require([
  'app','kendo'
], function (app,kendo) {
    app.initialize();
});
```

app.js

```
define([
    'router'
], function (router) {
    var initialize = function () {
        router.start();
    };
    return {
        initialize: initialize
    };
});
```

RouteConfig.cs

```
public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Spa", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

Spa.cshtml

```
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Spa";
Layout = null; // "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
<link href="@Url.Content("~/content/kendo/kendo.common.min.css")"        rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="@Url.Content("~/content/kendo/kendo.mobile.all.min.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="@Url.Content("~/content/kendo/kendo.dataviz.min.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="@Url.Content("~/content/kendo/kendo.default.min.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="@Url.Content("~/content/kendo/kendo.dataviz.default.min.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="@Url.Content("~/scripts/require.js")" data-main="/webapitest2/scripts/app/main"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Index.cshtml

```
<span>#: foo #</span>
<script id="index" type="text/x-kendo-template">
   <span>#: foo #</span>
</script>
```

Comment: I'm just now starting to tinker with Kendo myself... but the times I've gotten the '<' error have been when I'm expecting a json response and get html instead.  Hope this helps you track it down.

Comment: turns out it was a config issue. see my answer for details. Once you get the hang of kendo it is pretty awesome.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out tech support was correct. I am using the text plugin which basically allows for external text/template files to be loaded. However the path to the text.js file was incorrect and so was my default route in the router.js  . Turns out I was my own worst enemy. Instead of taking the time to read and do some research above and beyond the article I decided to hack blindly away at it breaking the config further and generating "false positive" errors which lead to this post.

Here is the corrected router.js

```
router.route("/", function() {
    require(['text!/webapitest2/home/index'], function(view) {
        loadView(indexmodel, view);
    });
});

//['text!/home/index']
router.route("/webapitest2/home/index", function() {
    require(['text!/webapitest2/home/index'], function(view) {
        loadView(indexmodel, view);
    });
});
```

Note the **text!** in the require function. So using this example is ['path to text plugin' **!** 'path to template']  .

here is the new main.js

```
require.config({
    paths: {
        // Packages
        'text': '../text',
        'router': 'router',
        "jquery": "../kendo/jquery.min",
        "kendo": "../kendo/kendo.all.min",
        "jszip":"../kendo/jszip.min",
        "aspnetmvc": "../kendo/kendo.aspnetmvc.min"
    },
    shim: {
        'kendo': ['jquery']
    },
    priority: ['text', 'router', 'app']
});
require([
    'app','kendo'
], function (app,kendo) {
    app.initialize();
});
```

If I am understanding it correctly the path config is relative to where the main.js is located.

Disclaimer, this is what it took for me to get my test to work and how and why I think it is working. I am only on day 2 of requireJS so I could be completely wrong and just got lucky.